# Why does Azure Time Series Insights GET availability response distribution have entry with Datetime.MinValue?

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I have currently an working Azure TSI environment in use.

At the moment environment **GET** request for both store types

```
https://XXX.env.timeseries.azure.com/availability?api-version=2020-07-31&storeType=ColdStore
https://XXX.env.timeseries.azure.com/availability?api-version=2020-07-31&storeType=WarmStore
```

have started to return `DateTime.MinValue` in their availability `range.from` value. The response below is observed in the Time Series Insights user interface and by the Chrome development tools network tab:

```
{
    "availability":{
        "intervalSize":"P3600D",
        "distribution":{
            "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z":371427749,
            "2020-04-15T00:00:00Z":1499591,
            ...
            "2011-09-21T00:00:00Z":137643193
        },
        "range":{
            "from":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "to":"2021-07-03T07:05:49.182Z"
        }
    },
    "retention":"P7D"
}
```

Is this a bug? I can easily work around the issues by selecting the oldest valid value on distribution. However, I am wondering what the distribution response with `DateTime.MinValue` tries to express?

[Link to the Microsoft Time Series Insights documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/query/get-availability)

EDIT:

This seems to be an effect of me sending data into the TSI with an incorrect timestamp. Where timestamp is equivalent to `DateTime.MinValue`. Therefore the response of TSI is correct. However, it seems that in this particular case the `warmstorage` response of TSI:

```
availability?api-version=2020-07-31&storeType=WarmStore

{
  "availability": {
    "intervalSize": "P3600D",
    "distribution": {
      "2011-09-21T00:00:00Z": 132976370,
      "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z": 371393382
    },
    "range": {
      "from": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "to": "2021-07-05T14:36:16.439Z"
    }
  },
  "retention": "P7D"
}
```

does not give me enough data to determine the correct `warmstorage` range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ingested event that has timestamp of '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' is skewing the results. The availability above provides the range based on the timestamps of the events ingested. We don't have a way to filter events via the availability API.

You will need to wait until those events get dropped from warm store due to retention. TSI Gen2 warm store retention period is 31 days.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the Azure Table Storage does not accept values with `DateTime.MinValue` and returns a bad request. Might be worthwhile to consider the same logic here? and logging a proper error on those messages.